# When is the integral $\int_S 1/t dt$ for $S$ a certain Lebesgue measurable set infinite?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $S$ be a compact set of $\mathbb{R}$ such that:

- $m(S) >0.$

We can then consider the integral $$\int_S \frac{1}{t} dt.$$

My question is:
Under what conditions on $S$ is it true that this integral is either $\infty$ or $-\infty?$

It is not true for all compact sets $S$ of positive measure containing $0.$ For example, if $0$ is an isolated point of $S$ then the integral is not infinite.  The condition seems to be something that $0$ should "carry enough measure", but I can not make sense of this. Any partial answers are welcome.

Comment: It is pretty difficult to give answers that aren't just restating the definition. Having positive lower density at $0$ (from the positive direction only) certainly implies that the integral is infinite. But it's not necessary.

Comment: @user296602 Why is positive lower density at  $0$ enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Added later:** Another idea is to observe that

$$\frac{1}{t} = \int_t^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}\, dx.$$

Put that into the integral

$$\tag 1 \int_0^\infty \frac{\chi_S(t)}{t}\,dt$$

and use Fubini. That will give

$$\tag 2 \int_0^\infty \frac{m(S\cap(0,x))}{x^2}\,dx.$$

So $(1)=(2).$ That could be helpful. For example $(2)$ gives the result on positive density you were asking about.

---

**Previous answer**: To get you started, let $I_n$ be the interval $[4^{-n}/2, 4^{-n}], \,n=1,2,\dots$ Think about

$$S= \{0\} \cup I_1 \cup I_2 \cup \cdots$$

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not see your point. Would you mind expanding on what you are getting at?

Comment: I should have written $S$ for $K.$ The point is to calculate $\int_S 1/t.$

Comment: I believe I have done that, but I still do not see what you are getting at. The sum seems to be $\sum_n \ln(2) = \infty.$

Comment: I thought the example would prove instructive. It was an example of  "$0$ carrying enough measure".

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for the example, I think it is a nice example of that idea. My hope was to get general situationa for when the integral is infinite. For example, it was mentioned in the comments that it is true if $0$ has positive upper density. This seems plausible, but I do not see how to show this.

Comment: Thanks, this was more the answer I was hoping for. Do you know if the statement holds in the situation when $0$ is a limit of points of positive density?

Comment: No, check out $S = \{0\}\cup I_1 \cup I_2 \cup \cdots $ where $I_n=[2^{-n}, 2^{-n}(1+1/n^2)].$